# Function doesn't write ReadLine() input to file

Tags: c#, string, list, file

I am making a helper for fun and decided to code it in C#.
It works as follows:

> The user is prompted how many libraries they want to include
> The libraries get appended in a `List<string>`
> The user is asked if they would like to include a `main` function
> The `main` function works, the includes don't
> Here's my code:

For the function that writes into the file:

```cs
static void CStart(string fileName, List<string> libraries, bool mainMethod)
{
    string final = "";
    string includes = "";
    foreach (string s in libraries)
    {
        includes += $"#include <{s}>\n";
    }
    includes += "\n";
    final += includes;
    if (mainMethod)
    {
        final += "int main(int argc, const char* argv[])\n{\n\t\n}";
    }
    File.WriteAllText(fileName, final);
}
```

And the main function:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Programming Helper!\nSelect an option:\n");
        Console.WriteLine("1) Write a C file\n");
        Console.Write("Choice: ");
        string ipt0 = Console.ReadLine();
        if (ipt0 == "1")
        {
            Console.Write("Please select a file path: ");
            string filePath = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("How many libraries would you like to include: ");
            string ipt = Console.ReadLine();
            List<string> libraries = new List<string>();
            if (ipt.All(Char.IsDigit))
            {
                int i = int.Parse(ipt);
                for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
                {
                    Console.Write("Write a library: ");
                    libraries.Append(Console.ReadLine());
                }
            }
            Console.Write("Would you like to generate a main function? [Yn]: ");
            string yn = Console.ReadLine();
            if (yn == "n" || yn == "N")
            {
                CStart(filePath, libraries, false);
            }
            else
            {
                CStart(filePath, libraries, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The file text is:

```c
int main(int argc, const char argv[])
{

}
```

I want my file to be:

```c
#include <one of the libraries specified>
#include <one of the libraries specified>
#include <one of the libraries specified>
...

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{

}
```

Note: `...` should be replaced with the other libraries demanded to include

Comment: At first glance, your code looks good. You described what you expect, but what did you observe instead? What was the input?

Comment: @KlausGütter Input: 1, c:\users\...\test.c, 1, stdio.h, y

Comment: libraries.Append(ipt); Try this.

Comment: Should be `libraries.Add`, not `libraries.Append`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have an empty `libraries` collection. Note, that `Append` in

```
libraries.Append(Console.ReadLine());
```

is a *Linq extension method* which creates a new `IEnumerable<string>` which you in turn *ignore*. You should use `Add` instead:

```
libraries.Add(Console.ReadLine());
```